# USB charging and powering circuit with MAX1555 and MAX1881

Tags: battery-charging, 3.3v

I'm new to (rechargeable) battery powered devices, but I found the [following article about using the MAX1555 and MAX1881](http://w3circuits.blogspot.co.at/2012/08/usb-charger-using-ic-max1555.html) for building a charging (via USB) and powering (µC-circuit, 3.3V, max. ~70mA) circuit. They describe the following diagram:

[image]

The [MAX1555](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1551-MAX1555.pdf) seems to fitting very well for my application. It is cheap, compact and easy to use.

But the [MAX1881](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1778-MAX1885.pdf) looks uneconomical for my application. It has a lot of functions, it is rather large and the datasheet describes another usage area for this IC. Its particular advantage seems to be reverse battery protection.

Does anybody has experience with the MAX1881 or does anybody know a good alternative?

Comment: Are you sure you looked into the correct data sheet? Its a **8** 881 in the schematic, you linked to **1** 881. These are very different chips.

Comment: You're right. I've read it wrong. With the MAX8881 the circuit does make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MAX **8881** EUT33 is a LDO in the first place. Note that the battery voltage maximum is 4.2 Volts when charging - which is too high for many 3.3 V circuits - so you need a voltage regulator in most cases anyway.

The part is SOT23-6 and $0.86 @ 1k (from Maxims website), so both small and cheap.

Comment: +1 Well spotted although I think the data sheet should have given it away to the OP

Comment: You're right. I've read it wrong. MAX8881 seems fitting much better.